# change the name of SharePoint 2013 Farm SQL server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

i am needing to rename my SharePoint farm SQL DB server i have been told that i would have to fully recreate the farm to rename the sql server.

i am needing to rename it to SQLSERVRE2 original naming being SQLSERVER

is there any other options?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. have you set up the SQL Alias and used that to connect SQL
2. or use the DNS alias or simply server name

If you use alias then its very simple to rename.I would shut down the sharepoint, rename the server and update the SQL alias on the servers and start the SharePoint, everything will be work.

If no Alias then you have to rebuild the farm because their is no supported way to update the config db connection string.

But still you have your Content DB and Serivces db their so once you rebuild the farm then you can attach old DBs to new farm.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: yes i used run>cliconfg.exe to create a TCP/IP Alias pointing to the new sqlserver name and it running fine cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PowerShell command [Rename-SPServer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/rename-spserver?view=sharepoint-ps) to rename SQL server.

Rename-SPServer -Identity "SQLSERVRE" -Name "SQLSERVRE2"